# Switch-Case syntax in Mason

Tags: perl, switch-statement, mason

I am looking for the switch-case syntax in Mason, but haven't been able to find one.

Could someone please assist with a sample here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Saket, the following works fine on my Mason system. It is `HTML::Mason` ver. 1.48 running on Perl 5.14 and Apache 2.2.22.

The switch-like statements `given`/`when` are available after Perl `5.10.1`, (**[see here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements)**), as has been pointed out already in the other posting from Matteo.

`test.html` (rename to `test.mas` if your server configuration requires this).

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
% my $name = 'Wittig';
  <h3>Hello <% $name %>! Ist this your <% swordname($name) %>?</h3>
  </body>
</html>

<%perl>
 sub swordname  {
   my $hero = shift;
   my $sword;
   given($hero) {
      when (/^Luno/)      { $sword = 'Fingal'   }
      when (/^Ecke/)      { $sword = 'Eckesax'  }
      when (/^Artus/)     { $sword = 'Excalibur'}
      when (/^Wittig/)    { $sword = 'Mimung'   }
      when (/^Ortnit/)    { $sword = 'Rosen'    }
      when (/^Sigurd/)    { $sword = 'Gram'     }
      when (/^Siegmund/)  { $sword = 'Notung'   }
      when (/^Siegfried/) { $sword = 'Balmung'  }
      when (/^Dietrich/)  { $sword = 'Nagelring'}
      default:            { $sword = 'Sword'    }
   }
   return $sword;
 }
</%perl>

<%once>
 use feature "switch";
</%once>
```

---

The module `Switch.pm` which belonged to the Perl core modules [before 5.14.0](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Removed_Modules_and_Pragmata) (as David Cross noted in comment), did provide a more "switch-like" syntax but used a source filter. It can be still used after beeing [installed by hand](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/Switch-2.16/Switch.pm) (`cpan install Switch`) but is not recommended. The example can be rewritten using `Switch.pm`:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
% my $name = 'Wittig';
  <h3>Hello <% $name %>! Ist this your <% swordname($name) %>?</h3>
  </body>
</html>

<%perl>
 sub swordname  {
   my $hero = shift;
   switch($hero) {
      case 'Luno'      { return 'Fingal'   }
      case 'Ecke'      { return 'Eckesax'  }
      case 'Artus'     { return 'Excalibur'}
      case 'Wittig'    { return 'Mimung'   }
      case 'Ortnit'    { return 'Rosen'    }
      case 'Sigurd'    { return 'Gram'     }
      case 'Siegmund'  { return 'Notung'   }
      case 'Siegfried' { return 'Balmung'  }
      case 'Dietrich'  { return 'Nagelring'}
      else             { return 'Sword'    }
   }
 }
</%perl>

<%once>
 use Switch;
</%once>
```

---

But the most simple "equivalent" of a switch that depends only on a fixed key, would, of course, be a `%hash`:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
% my $name = 'Wittig';
  <h3>Hello <% $name %>! Ist this your <% $NameSword{$name} %>?</h3>
  </body>
</html>

<%once>
 my %NameSword = (
   Luno      => 'Fingal',
   Ecke      => 'Eckesax',
   Artus     => 'Excalibur',
   Wittig    => 'Mimung',
   Ortnit    => 'Rosen',
   Sigurd    => 'Gram',
   Siegmund  => 'Notung',
   Siegfried => 'Balmung',
   Dietrich  => 'Nagelring'
 );
</%once>
```

All three variants produce the same output. Maybe I mixed up the sword names (will correct if necessary).

Comment: The given/when statement was introduced to replace Switch.pm. Switch.pm is a source filter and is therefore NOT recommended for production code. Switch.pm has been removed from the standard Perl distribution from Perl 5.14. You can still get it from CPAN, but the recommendation is that you don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a switch statement in Perl, put `#switch $var` at the beginning of the logic block. That is only to indicate you intend to do logic on only one variable. For the classic case of a break after every case, you can use `if elsif else` block.

```
$var = 3;

# switch $var
if   ($var == 1) {print "one\n";   }
elsif($var == 2) {print "two\n";   }
elsif($var == 3) {print "three\n"; }
elsif($var == 4) {print "four\n";  }
else             {print "didn't get it\n"; } #default
```

If you intend to use fall through and default, then it is more complicated and slower.

```
$var = 3;
$got = 0;
# switch $var
if   ($var == 1) {print "one\n";   ++$got;}
if   ($var == 2) {print "two\n";   ++$got;}
if   ($var == 3) {print "three\n"; ++$got;}
if   ($var == 3 
     || $var == 4) {print "three or four\n"; ++$got} #fall-through
unless ($got)      {print "didn't get it\n"; } #default
```

Answer (score -1):

Perl did not have a switch/case statement until recently

You can use the [Switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/Switch.html) module

```
use Switch;

switch ($val) {
    case 1          { print "number 1" }
    case "a"        { print "string a" }
    case [1..10,42] { print "number in list" }
    case (\@array)  { print "number in list" }
    case /\w+/      { print "pattern" }
    case qr/\w+/    { print "pattern" }
    case (\%hash)   { print "entry in hash" }
    case (\&sub)    { print "arg to subroutine" }
    else            { print "previous case not true" }
}
```

or use the [`given/when` constructs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements) of Perl 6 available from Perl 5.10

Example:

```
use v5.10.1;

given ($var) {
    when (/^abc/) { $abc = 1 }
    when (/^def/) { $def = 1 }
    when (/^xyz/) { $xyz = 1 }
    default       { $nothing = 1 }
}
```

Comment: i believe that's with pure Perl code, and not mason. I tried using this in mason, but to no success. would you have a mason sample

Comment: But then you can embed Perl code in HTML. You can have your switch statement in `<%perl>` sections. You should maybe edit your question and give an example of what you want to do.

Comment: yes, that's what i'm doing...but looks like mason does not quite understand the 'use' statement, and hence the switch syntax fails

Comment: @Saket if you proveide the error message, and the context of the code that causes the error, we can help diagnose the mason error.  I have a ton of mason code in front of me right now, and if your 'use' stanements aren't in the block that are specifically for perl code (init shared, perl, etc.) then yes, mason will puke on it when it reads it.  I put mine in %init mostly, but I have one in a %filter block as well.

Comment: Switch.pm was introduced with Perl 5.8.0. It was removed from Perl 5.14. You should use given/when instead (introduced with Perl 5.10.0).

Comment: @DaveCross Yes for this reason I included both in my answer: many systems (e.g., RedHat) still have old Perl version. You can't assume that Perl 5.10 is there.

Comment: @Matteo: True, but I also don't think that you should be recommending Switch.pm. It's a source filter and therefore shouldn't go anywhere near production code :-)

Answer (score -1):

On Perl 5.10.1 given/when works fine for me. Here is the example-component I used to test:

```
% my $value=2;
% given ($value) {
%     when (1) {
<h1>It is one, dear</h1>
%     }
%     when (2) {
<h2>Level two</h2>
%     }
% }
%
<%once>
use v5.10.1;
</%once>
```

If I set $value to 1, I get the h1-part; setting it to 2 gives me the h2-part.